# Icons appearing beside menu options

Tags: menu, icons

This suddenly started happening, and I don't know why...But I suspect that I bumped something. Does anyone know what may cause these icons to appear?

[image]

Beside "Create New Folder" and "Create New Document" and "Paste" have never had these icons beside them before. I don't mind them, but I want to know where they came from.

This happens on Ubuntu/Ubuntu 2D, GNOME/GNOME Classic, and Cinnamon desktop environments.

Comment: Have you recently installed a new icon theme or desktop theme?

Comment: I have not. I did, however, recently just install GNOME 3. Could that have done it? I removed GNOME 3 and it still remained.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have `dconf-editor` installed:

[image]

...

and one more command line alternative:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface menus-have-icons false
```

Comment: how to do it via myunity?

Comment: ... cool - you found a regression.  I'll file a bug report for precise.

Comment: Excellent, that did it! I'm not sure how they appeared, but that took them away. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

**ubuntutweak > tweaks > miscellaneous**

[image]

**ubuntutweak > tweaks > miscellaneous**

Alternatively you can use dconf-editor or gconf-editor

[image]

Comment: I don't have Ubuntu Tweak installed. Is there a command I could run to edit the file Ubuntu Tweak would edit?

Comment: settings maybe changed during gnome-shell installation ,dconf-editor may can fix it